# replace string value with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of strings, within each string I want to call a variable

```
Strings = ["$username thanks for visiting","Thanks $username, but I don't understand the command $userProvidedCommand"]
```

now I know I can use string replace

```
msg.replace('$username', userame)
```

however I don't want to write a string replace for every possibility.

what would be ideal , I think. would be to have have some sort of pattern replacement  where it looks for the $ and breaks the string up and concatenates it back together with the variable.

Is there a way to do that, or maybe there is a better solution ?

thanks

Comment: Sorry just gonna dump a link http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Comment: could you not provide a key for each string as well ? then replace by key? Loop over arrays and replace each key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with regular expressions:

```
var data = {
  username: 'peterpan',
  userProvidedCommand: 'mycommand'
}

var format = function(data, str) {
  return str.replace(/\$(\w+)/g, function(_, m) {
    return data[m] || ''
  })
}

var result = strings.map(format.bind(null, data))
```

Comment: I think this will get me where I'm going , thank you for prompt answer

Comment: quick question what if i don't have all the variables in a nice neat object

Comment: @mcgrailm, I'd just put them in an object, in ES6 there's even a shortcut for that `{a:a,b:b,c:c} === {a,b,c}`